# iOS "Touch to Return to Navigation" style Banner

Tags: ios, controls

In the phone App or the Maps App if the App is in the background a glowing "Bar" appears on the top that the user can touch to return to the App.  For the Apple Maps app - this is a "Touch to Return to Navigation"

What is this Control called?

Are there any best practices on when to use and when not to use this control.

Is the Glowing built into this control

Comment: The closest you can get is by enabling VOIP, which looks just like the In-Call status bar. However, it's only available if you are actually using VOIP, and there is no public api for having a custom bar be present while the app is not running.

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this? I'm using one with a recorder, but since my app doesn't actually record, I'd like to use a different approach if possible. It's a navigation app, just like the maps app.

Comment: This is in the Apple Maps app, but it also appears when using the Google Maps app; which indicates that any app can do the same thing. It isn't normally seen in GPS apps, but I'm still looking for how it is enabled.

Comment: I don't believe this is a public API, at least at this point in time (iOS 9). You can trigger them for VOIP as said or by using location (e.g. Google Maps is using your location).